# AsyncTask in onItemClick() & configuration change

Tags: android, configuration, android-asynctask

I load a list of some data. I do it in AsyncTask and I also use lastNonConfigurationInstance, so when I change the configuration of a device, list is not loaded again. Everything is clear here. 
BUT when I click on an item, the "extended" data of this item is loaded. And here I'm not sure what to do... Should I use another AsyncTask for downloading data of the item or just do it directly in onItemClick()? If I put it in AsyncTask I should also remember about configuration change and in this case I should also use lastNonConfigurationInstance? 
Thanks in advance for all your suggestions, answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "extended" data taken more than 20ms to fetch, you should consider using AsyncTask for this too.

If your data is quick to fetch, you don't need  `lastNonConfigurationInstance`. Seems like you could just save you "current index" of the item the user clicked on in the `onSaveInstanceData`. When your activity is recreated in `onCreate(Bundle)` read the selected index from the bundle and load data for the sub item.

If your extended data takes time, then you could use the `lastNonConfigurationInstance` mechanism to save data for the currently selected item.

Comment: Thank You very much. I will consider what to do ;)